# Need to update data from my database to a php variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, mysqli

i'm facing an issue that i'm unable to solve. I've changed my coding approach 3 times in a row. It's basically like this:

1. A user uploads images, these images get uploaded to a local folder + their names in a database where i then fetch them and load them.
2. A user may edit his images, I've done this through checkbox selection and a button called "Delete selected images". When the button is pressed, an post request through ajax is sent and the new images list is updated into the database and in the folder too without refreshing the page.
3. My issue is here: Say i had in the database these images: 0.png,1.png,2.png and i deleted the third image 2.png. The database field will be updated to : 0.png,1.png but then if i delete one more image let's say the first image,  the database field should now be: 1.png but instead it becomes 1.png, 2.png,this is happening because the variable containing the images is not being updated from the database after every delete. Let's say $row['images'] was fetched from the database but it is not getting updated.

I need help on how to update my php variables from my database after sending the post request with ajax.

Comment: PHP is a request-response scripting language, unless you implement persistence (through sessions for example), variables do not hold their value.

That being said, could you please supply some code? Without seeing anything you wrote we can't really help you get any further. It also sounds like you are storing all images in 1 field, I'd suggest more normalized approach and split those off in a separate table.

Comment: Start sharing some code. Your question makes little sense now. Also share the db structure: do you have a record for each image or one record where you store all images in one field??

Comment: @LelioFaieta All images for each user is stored in one field called images: 1.png,2.png,3.png etc.. So you'd have your own row with the images field and i'd have my own row with the images field.

Comment: @mub you should have one table with user definition. Another table with user_id in one column and file name in the other. In this second table you will have one row for each file. This will also fix your issue with the code.

Comment: Added code for more clarification.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Even if i did that, my variable isn't getting updated after ajax sends the post requests and deletes the image. let's say i deleted first image, nothing updates the the images variable coming the database.

Comment: to delete a file you just do `DELETE FROM filelist WHERE user=user_id AND filename="2.png"` After this, in the same ajax call you do a `SELECT filename WHERE user=user_id` and you return to your page the array of left images

Comment: @LelioFaieta my ajax call code is on one page and the code for deleting the images is on another, say i fetch back to the main page the array of left images, how do i insert it into the php variable?

Comment: this is the problem: $imagesindb =  explode(",",$_POST['imagesindb']); That isn't updated. Instead get that value from your DB

Comment: how can i do that? like send post data from my deleteimages.php back to my index.php

Comment: No, in Deleteimages.php fetch the field from the database instead of getting it from $_POST and explode it, that gives you the actual images that are in the database

Comment: but you would be better off just putting all images in another table, one row per image, along with the ID.

Comment: @verhie THANK YOU!!! I LOVE YOU!

Comment: that escalated quickly :)